# Where to limit the Related Products in Magento

Tags: magento, product

I would like to ask about Related Products in Magento.
In Magento Admin, I checked 20 products as a related product of Product"A".
I write `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('related'); ?>` in `view.phtml` file. 
I copy `related.phtml` file from core file and I edited the layout of Related Products View. 
When I run the site, it only shows 11 related products. I don't know why. I already made "clear cached" and "Re-Indexed".
Please Help me..

Comment: Please check remaining products are visible on frontend

Answer (score 3):

It's set in the layout XML. The default value is 4, as you can see in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml`:

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
    <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
    <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>4</limit></action>
</block>
```

It can be changed for example to `20` in a custom theme, using the following layout XML:

```
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info.upsell">
            <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>20</limit></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

(for *no limit*, enter `0` as the limit parameter)

This should be in `layout/local.xml` or a theme specific layout file. Do **not** copy and modify the original `catalog.xml`!